# Flask correct variable value on terminal but not in HTML template

Tags: python, flask

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008277/html-variable-value-is-not-changing-in-flask) which does not solve my problem.

I have a Flask app which reads from a database and renders an HTML template using the DB data. I'm trying to manipulate a value I get from the DB before sending it to the HTML template and this doesn't work.

Python code:

```
@app.route('/pilot', methods=['GET'])
def form_view():
    result = {}
    # query DB and get cursor

    numQuestions = 0
    for row in cursor:
        row.pop('_id', None)        # delete the key and add modified key back
        row['_id'] = row['stage'][-1] # get only last char- eg, "1" from "stage1", "2" from "stage2" and so on
        print(row['_id'])
        result[numQuestions] = row
        numQuestions += 1

    return render_template("form.html", count=numQuestions, result=result, debug=app.debug)
```

Output when run on terminal is as expected:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

Jinja2 fragment of form.html:

```
{% for row in result[row_num]['scrutiny_stage'] %}
    {{ row['_id'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Output on browser:

```
stage1 stage1 stage1 stage2 stage2 stage2 stage2
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here and how I can get the correct value of the variable I'm setting in the Python code to show up in the HTML template being rendered by Flask?

Thanks.

Comment: This code can't give that result. The `result` object you pass to the template doesn't have a `scrutiny_stage` nested dictionary. And what is `row_num` in that template? You'll need to show real code if you want us to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: You print (row['_id']) and add row to the result dict, of course there is a difference there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips folks, even though I couldn't share all the context (since I have to protect proprietary info), they were helpful. I managed to solve this with multiple steps:

1. I redid my DB schema so that every document has an '_id' key with a plain numeric value. I dropped the 'stage': 'stage1' kinds of fields. The 'stage' is now computed dynamically in the code base on the DB query results.
2. Then I changed the Flask view function to add a 'stage' key to the result dict being passed to the HTML template (no mucking around with the '_id' field):

```
numQuestions = 0

for row in cursor:
    for line in row['scrutiny_stage']:
        row['stage'] = line['_id']

    result[numQuestions] = row
    numQuestions += 1
```

3. Finally, in my Jinja2 block, I realized that I need to operate over the result as a dict, so I changed it to use the dict.values() method:

```
    {% for row in result.values() %}
        {{ row['stage'] }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Now, I get the same values printed in the terminal as well as in my browser.